# Undefined reference when using OpenCV and CMake in VSCode

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

Im trying to use OpenCV in VSCode and followed this videos instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9HBM1m_EMU&t=3s&ab_channel=NicolaiNielsen-ComputerVision%26AI

Difference from the video is im using mingw compiler and im unable to get the msvc compiler (Not the issue though).

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "aa" << std::endl;
 
    std::string img = "lenna.jpg";
    Mat srcImage = imread(img);
    if (!srcImage.data) {
        return 1;
    }
    imshow("srcImage", srcImage);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(OpenCV_Test VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(OpenCV_Test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(OpenCV_Test ${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Im able to get it to compile and output "aa" if i remove everything with OpenCV, but adding it gives me this compile error:

```
[main] Building folder: OpenCVTest 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/Users/Chris/Desktop/OpenCVTest/build --config Debug --target all -j 10 --
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target OpenCV_Test
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/OpenCV_Test.dir/main.cpp.obj
[build] [100%] Linking CXX executable OpenCV_Test.exe
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/OpenCV_Test.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/OpenCVTest/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/OpenCV_Test.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): in function `main':
[build] C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/OpenCVTest/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/OpenCVTest/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/OpenCVTest/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/OpenCVTest/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/OpenCV_Test.dir/build.make:117: OpenCV_Test.exe] Error 1
[build] make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:839: CMakeFiles/OpenCV_Test.dir/all] Error 2
[build] make: *** [Makefile:121: all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: unclear, which opencv lib(s) it is trying to link, but if you are using mingw, you cannot use ths prebuilt libs, they are for VS only. means, you have to *build* the opencv libs from src first